# How can I use cmake to download and build ALSA and PortAudio libraries while building audacity from source?

Tags: cmake, alsa, conan, portaudio, audacity

I'm trying to debug audacity that I build from source. The build process is managed by cmake, and the dependencies are handled by conan. 2 main dependencies are portAudio and ALSA libraries.
I'd like to integrate building of these 2 libraries into the building process of audacity, instead of using libraries downloaded by conan.
The documentation for audacity explains how to disable conan altogather. But how can I configure cmake to download and build these libraries as a part of the building process of audacity, so that I can debug the libraries as well?

Audacity uses cmake to build, and conan to download its dependencies. I'm using GDB to debug it in Linux.

Comment: There is no simple solution to this. You can try to use CMake FetchContent utilities and similar strategies to download and build from CMake, but it might be far from easy, I wouldn't recommend for non CMake expert.

Comment: using conan with CMake is a little bit intrusive in that it can mean writing the CMake project config in terms of conan-specific details, which I see some of [the audacity CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/audacity/audacity/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). I think you're better off looking in the direction of building conan packages locally, and then finding out how to point your audacity build to the locally-built conan packages (assuming that's possible. I don't know much conan).